# Motivic cohomology commutes with field extension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory, motivic-cohomology

$\DeclareMathOperator\Cor{Cor}$Let $X$ be a smooth scheme over $k$ and $k \subset F$ a field extension. Let $X_F$ be the field extension of $X$. Then there is a map
$$\varinjlim_{k\subset E \subset F} H^{p,q}(X_E,A) \longrightarrow H^{p,q}(X_F,A) .$$
Then Lemma 3.9 in [Lecture Notes on Motivic Cohomology](http://www.claymath.org/library/monographs/cmim02.pdf) asserts that this map is an isomorphism. However, the reason is the isomorphism
$$\varinjlim_{k\subset E \subset F}\mathbb{Z}(q)^p(X_E) = \varinjlim_{k\subset E \subset F} \Cor_E(X_E\times \mathbb{A}_1^{p-q},\mathbb{G}_m^q)=\Cor_F(X_F\times \mathbb{A}_1^{p-q},\mathbb{G}_m^q).$$
I do not know how this isomorphism implies the previous one. In fact, this colimit is taken over underlying space instead of a colimit of sheaves, so we cannot use the fact that sheaf cohomology commutes with colimits.

Comment: TeX note: $\displaystyle\varinjlim_{k \subset E \subset F}$ `\varinjlim_{k \subset E \subset F}` typesets better than $\displaystyle\underset{k \subset E \subset F}{\lim_{\rightarrow}}$ `\underset{k \subset E \subset F}{\lim_{\rightarrow}}`.  Also, $\operatorname{Cor}_E(\cdots)$ `\operatorname{Cor}_E(\cdots)` typesets better than $Cor_E(\cdots)$ `Cor_E(\cdots)`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: An alternative source for this would be Theorem 11.1.24 in arXiv:0912.2110. The main technical properties you might want to understand concretely are discussed in section 10.3 of loc. cit. (in particular 10.3.17 and 10.3.19).

Comment: Name of @D.-C.Cisinski's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416848/motivic-cohomology-commutes-with-field-extension#comment1069701_416848):  [Cisinski and Déglise - Triangulated categories of mixed motives](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.2110).

Comment: You can make the base spaces all match simply by derived pushforwarding everything onto $X$. Note that pushforwards preserve injectivity and derived pushforwards do not change cohomology although they change the base space.